# Suggestions to Purchase a System76 Ubuntu Pre-Installed Laptop

Tags: laptop

I am looking to buy a new laptop that well supports Ubuntu, and recently came across the Ubuntu laptop manufactured by [System76](https://www.system76.com/laptops/). I am not familiar with this brand although it seems to me they produce Ubuntu laptop with good performance. The price listed on their website is also not that expensive as compared with a MacBook Pro, or ThinkPad T series, or the [Dell XPS Developer Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/dell/dellxps)

Thus I hope to ask your opinions before buying. Has anyone used System76 Ubuntu Laptop? How is the experience. Is it worth to put the money on? I plan to invest $1k for a new laptop. Or even if it is not, would you recommend some other good brands?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware recommendation.

Comment: did they enough my friend ?

Comment: @user68186 I am actually thinking that , its also linked to Ubuntu somehow and we are here to Ask about Ubuntu. am I right my friend ?

Comment: Unfortunately [shopping recommendations are off topic on this site](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) so this question may be closed soon.  Yoi can ask this question on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) however.

Answer (score 2):

If you want opinions , I can say on behalf of all System76 users that They are working awesome even after years.

If you want to see those users opinions here we go their google plus post which filled with opinions.

[image]

https://plus.google.com/104919222657565747428/posts/XRmZ8y5pvmY

Comment: I tried to buy one used. Almost impossible to find. That should be a very good hint...